# How can I add separate width to each name and value that are getting iterated by ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I add separate `width` to each *name* and *value* that are getting iterated by:

**ng-repeat** in *angularJS*

For e.g: This is my data:

```
[
{
    "name": "First Name",
    "value": "Harry"
},
{
    "name": "Last Name",
    "value": "Potter"
},
{
    "name": "Gender",
    "value": "Male"
},
{
    "name": "DOB",
    "value": "21/5/1988"
},
{
    "name": "SSN",
    "value": "298456147"
}]
```

HTML:

```html
<div>
  <div ng-repeat=\ "data in data\">
    <div style=\ "float:left\">{{data.name}}</div>
    <div style=\ "float:left\">{{data.value}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, for each *name* and *value* I need separate `width`.

where can I add my width properties?

Comment: when this render in your *Browser* check your *HTML* with *browser console* for the *HTML tag* in which it renders, then write *CSS* for them as well for a better data display.

Comment: Why don't use just add a `width` field to each element in the array?

Comment: I added HTML also can u people pls take a look again.

Comment: I don't want width to each element in array . I want width to every pair @AndrewShepherd

Comment: For name and value together i want width of let's say 250px @AndrewShepherd

Comment: I have posted one approach below. See if it fulfills your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Add the "track by $index" clause as described in the docs for ng-repeat.

`ng-repeat="opt in data track by $index"`

Then you can use {{opt.name}} and {{opt.value}} and put them in different html elements with separate styles.

Comment: I didn't get U!! I think this doesn't work for my need

Comment: Dont use data in data. Use obj in data. Also make sure data is in $scope.  add another div to debug that shows {{data}} before the ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of your possible widths like

```
$scope.widthArray = ['100px','300px','200px']
```

Then set width like below in ng-repeat on element

```
ng-style="{width: widthArray[$index]}"
```

You can arrange your widths as per your requirement in array.